# Flush some equation lines to the left or right

Tags: math-mode, align

Is there a way to flush some equation lines to the left and flush other linesto the right?

In the following example, I want the first line to be flushed to the left, while the second line to be flushed to the right so that neither line is cropped while still utilizing the full width of the paper.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \text{\lipsum[1][1]}\\
  &&=\text{\lipsum[1][1]}\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I also tried using `flalign` but could not achieve this result.

Comment: I have math symbols rather than `lipsum`, I just use it as a placeholder instead of writing random math characters until I reach the needed width. I could break the equation into two math environments and use your suggestion, but this would be problematic when labelling the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `multline` is for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % twocolumn for smaller snapshot

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{multline*}
a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h\\i+j+k+l+m+o+p+q
\end{multline*}
Text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Image of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) should be avoided. References, however, are encouraged.